# Server Controls Inside a JavaScript Block

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to render a list of items from a database as a block of JSON so I can use it on the client side via JavaScript. I thought the best way to do this would be to use a Repeater or ListView to render my items, but I get a "server tag is not well formed" error.

This is my code

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="rptAddresses" ItemPlaceholderID="plcItems">
        <LayoutTemplate> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var addressConfig = [
                    <asp:Placeholder ID="plcItems" runat="server"/>
                ];
             </script>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            {
                'id': '<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("AddressID") %>" />',
                'name':...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are doing wrong, but it is probably your literal. You can just do this instead:

```
'id': '<%# Eval("AddressID") %>'
```

That said there are other alternatives to sending an array to your script:

[ClientScriptManager.RegisterArrayDeclaration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerarraydeclaration(v=vs.110).aspx) is built into the framework. Here's an example taken from the linked page:

```
' Define the array name and values.
Dim arrName As String = "MyArray"
Dim arrValue As String = """1"", ""2"", ""text"""
' Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript

' Register the array with the Page class.
cs.RegisterArrayDeclaration(arrName, arrValue)
```

This will render the following array just before the close of your form:

```
var MyArray =  new Array("1", "2", "text");
```

Personally, I prefer using the [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) because you can freely serialize basically any object:

```
Protected Function GetArray() As String
  Dim exampleList As New List(Of Pair) From {New Pair(7, 4), New Pair("Foo", "Bar")}
  Dim serializer As New Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
  Return serializer.Serialize(exampleDictionay)
End Function
```

You can then add it to your .aspx file anywhere you like:

```
var myArray = <%=GetArray()%>;
```

which actually renders as an array literal:

```
var myArray = [{"First":7,"Second":4},{"First":"Foo","Second":"Bar"}];
```

Of course, you could also do it completely in your aspx markup:

```
<% Dim serializer As New Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer() %>
var array = <%= serializer.Serialize({"look", "at", "this"})%>;
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this seems like one solution but I get the impression it adds a lot of visual boilerplate. I found a (fairly) elegant solution below.

Answer (score 1):

After much tweaking with all combination of single and double quotes, I eventually solved this by putting the `<script>` tag in a literal. ie:

```
    <LayoutTemplate> 
        <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<script type="text/javascript">' />
            var macroConfig = [
                <asp:Placeholder ID="plcItems" runat="server"/>
            ];
            $(document).ready(function () {
                ...
            });
        <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='</script>' />
    </LayoutTemplate>
```

It seems the parser gets confused with where the `script` tag ends and the server control tag starts.